# Using _str_ method to define a library

Tags: python, string, class, methods

I am working on a python practice question: A class called Book has already been partially defined. You are tasked with completing the class definition. Book takes two input variables in the following order, title and author, which are strings. There should be two instance variables, title, and author. You should create 1 method for Book. The method will be the **str** method. When an instance of the book class is printed out, it should use the following format: "Author: {author name here}, Title: {title of book here}."

I have read different guides and tried the following code, but still get an error message. Can someone help me explain what I am doing off?

**Code entered:**

```
class Book():
    def __init__(self,title, author):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
    def __str__(self):
        return ("Author:"+self.author,"Title:"+self.title)

Book1 = Book("Pride and Prejudice","Jane Austen")

print(Book1)
```

**Error message:**

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        10 Book1 = Book("Pride and Prejudice","Jane Austen")
>        11 
>   ---> 12 print(Book1)
>
> TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type tuple)

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
def __str__(self):
   return ("Author:"+self.author,"Title:"+self.title)
```

is indeed returning a 2-tuple:

```
def __str__(self):
   return (
       "Author:"+self.author,
       "Title:"+self.title,
   )
```

If you're using Python 3.6+, you're looking for

```
def __str__(self):
   return f"Author: {self.author}, Title: {self.title}"
```

or for compatibility with all versions,

```
def __str__(self):
   return f"Author: %s, Title: %s" % (self.author, self.title)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. What if I use Python 3.0? Do you know if it is the same fix as in 3.6?

Comment: Yes, it is. (For Python 2.x, you'd generally also define `__unicode__()`, but let's not talk about that.)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Author: {}, Title= {}'.format(self.author, self.title)
```

Comment: You could improve this answer for the community if you added some context to why you are suggesting this as an answer. Read more about improving answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer